# Does updating your application delete files?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I wrote a game that I plan on updating soon. The game generates a scoreboard when the application starts, if there is no scoreboard file present.

If people update to my latest version, will the scoreboard file (that's generated by the code itself, not a file that comes preloaded in the app) be deleted?

If so, is there any way to avoid this without any coding previously required?

Comment: While I'm **not** voting to close (this is a great question, and I've up-voted it), I'd suggest having a look over at [the Apple Stack Exchange site](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) to see if it might be potentially already answered there. And maybe posting there, too?

Comment: @David Thomas This is programming related - it's unlikely to have been answered on the generic Apple questions site.

Comment: @middaparka, I know it's programming related (hence the up-vote, the explicit " **not** voting to close" and suggestion for a cross-post, rather than migration). I've never been to the Apple site, but I assumed there would be general overlap between the Apple technology and Apple-specific development. Sort of an Apple-based Superuser.com. If that's not the case, I'll happily rescind my earlier suggestion.

Comment: @David Thomas Pretty sure that Apple site is more of a semi-medium-kinda-ish-user-whos-having-a-problem-with-their-ipod-starting.com ;-)

Comment: @middaparka, **excellent!** and +1; and in which case I'll probably never go visit... =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updated version of your app will simply replace the existing version's bundle - any files you've written to your app's document area will remain intact.

As such, you simply need to check for the presence of the file within your app's document area as per usual and write a "new" version if none exists.

Comment: Thanks very much! This was a big help!

Answer (score 0):

If the file is within your applications bundle, it will be deleted. Files saved with Core Data and NSUserDefaults will not. I've never personally written a file to the disk, so I don't know where the default write point is. You'll have to find this out yourself.

Happy coding,

Zane

Comment: Thanks for the information as to why my response wasn't good enough. I'll work to improve it. Heh.

Comment: -1 If you've "never personally written a file to the disk" you probably shouldn't attempt to answer this question. (Especially as a bundle based (and hence un-writable) high scores file makes no sense.) :-)

Comment: @middaparka: on the other hand, there's the ["It's okay to guess, but be honest"](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) philosophy. On the gripping hand, Aurum's answer doesn't add anything beyond middaparka's answer.

Comment: @outis @Aurum Aquila Yeah, probably a bit harsh on balance. I've removed my downvote.